# Generate "Unique" 5 digits ID with javascript (99999 combinations) in random order

Tags: javascript, uniqueidentifier

I want to generate an Unique 5 digits ID + 784 at the begining, the constraint, I can execute the script only one time, and I have to avoid the first 100 numbers so It can't be 00100 and lower. Since I use timestamp and I can execute only my script one time how I can handle this ?

I did this it's maybe dumb but at least I tried.

```
 ConcatedID();  
 function ConcatedID()
 {
  var uniqID = checkProtectedRange();
  if (checkProtectedRange())
    {
        var BarcodeID = 784 + uniqID;
        return BarcodeID;
    }
 else
        checkProtectedRange();
 }

 function checkProtectedRange()
{
var uniqueID = GenerateUniqueID();
var checkRange = uniqueID.substr(uniqueID.length - 3);
var checkRangeINT = parseInt(checkRange);
if (checkRangeINT <= 100)
        return (false);
else
        return (true);
 }

 function GenerateUniqueID()
{
var lengthID = 5;
var timestamp = + new Date();
var ts = timestamp.toString();
var parts = ts.split("").reverse();
var id = "";
var min  = 0;
var max = parts.length -1;
for (var i = 0; i < lengthID; ++i)
{
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    id += parts[index];
}
gs.log('Generate ID ' + id);
return id;                     
}
```

Comment: With only five digits, can you really call it unique?

Comment: @Ouroborus It has to work for a limited combinations but as to be unique for these combinations, I didn't chose the requirement...

Comment: there's simply not enough combination to make the number unquie, With 5 digits, you can have at most 99999 combinations, if you generate a number every second, you will run out of choice after ~27 min.

Comment: more 27 hours, which is 60 times better and no better

Comment: I note you reference "barcode" in there. Barcodes shouldn't be randomly generated. There are specific algorithms for a valid barcodes (a checksum), otherwise they should be sequential.

Comment: @AnthonyC Not enough combinations to make it unique?  That's not how uniqueness works.  You can have unique combinations with only 2 digits, just a lower number of them; don't conflate the amount with uniqueness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without being able to track previously used IDs, you're left with chance to prevent duplicates. Your shenanigans with `Date` doesn't really change that. See the [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem).

Given that, just follow the most straight-forward method: Generate a random string consisting of five digits.

```
function GenerateUniqueID() {
  return ('0000'+(Math.random() * (100000 - 101) + 101)|0).slice(-5);
}
```

Or, if you want just the final integer with constraints applied:

```
function GenerateUniqueID() {
  return (Math.random() * (78500000 - 78400101) + 78400101)|0;
}
```